# Python if statement not recognized

Tags: python, if-statement, bit

I'm trying to count the leading zeros in a bit string but for some reason, my program is not going into the if statements, even if i check with print statements and i does equal 0, the if statement is ignored.

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

```
bits = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(hex_int),16) #convert str into binary
counter = 0
for i in reversed(bits):
    print 'i: ', i
    if i == 0:
        print 'i: ', i
        counter+=1
    elif i==1:
        break
```

Comment: @GrantWinney sorry just updated it. bits is a binary conversion of a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
counter = 0
for i in reversed(bits):
    print 'i: ', i
    if i == '0':
        print 'i: ', i
        counter+=1
    elif i=='1':
        break
```

The problem is in the if-else statement. You must use a string instead of an integer. 
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! i just did isinstance(bits, str) and youre right, it's a string. This makes sense, thanks so much